# Update/ Add column in database

Tags: c#, database

im trying to update a column in my database. the column i want to update is noOfTrips. everytime the route is the same, the column noOfTrips must add 1. here is my code. i hope someone can help me with this problem.
 thanks in advance.

```
              string MyConS = "SERVER=localhost;" +
             "DATABASE=prototype_db;" +
             "UID=root;";`enter code here`


                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConS);
                MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                conn.Open();
                comm.CommandText = "Select RouteTo,RouteFrom,nOofTrips from tbl_bill_addtrips where RouteFrom = '" + txtBillRouteFrom.Text + "' and RouteTo ='" + txtBillRouteTo.Text + "'";
                MySqlDataReader Reader;
                Reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    int Trips = 1;
                    string to = Reader["RouteTo"].ToString();
                    string From = Reader["RouteFrom"].ToString();
                    Trips = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["nOofTrips"].ToString());


                    if (From.ToString() == txtBillRouteFrom.Text && to.ToString() == txtBillRouteTo.Text)
                    {
                        Trips++;
                        MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConS);
                        conn2.Open();
                        MySqlCommand command = conn2.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_bill_addtrips SET nOofTrips= '" + Trips.ToString() + "' where  RouteFrom='" + this.txtBillRouteFrom.Text + "'and RouteTo='" + this.txtBillRouteTo.Text + "'";


                    }
                }
```

Comment: Use parameter binding - this will save from sql injection style attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be ok at all but you must execute the updatecommand.

Use something like

> command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: yes it works! but it only update once, it doesn't update continously. it stops after it update once. the system just add another row with the same data, and the nOofTrips column doesn't update anymore. please i need a help.

Comment: Do i understand right: you want to increase nOofTrips each time a route-start/stops from your database matches the route-start/stops from "txtBillRoute"?

Comment: and the first run is ok but the secound one fails and the nOofTrips is the same as from run 1? Hmm.. please add an `conn2.Close()` at the end of your if-bracket and test again
needed anymore. Be shure not to "double-open" a conn

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "continously updating"? Maybe there's n mistake in your logic which call this comparison-request

Comment: can you give me an example code for your first reply? i'm confused already. please.

Comment: `if([your args])`
`{ [stuff] conn2.Open(); [stuff] conn2.Close();}` do i mean. It would help a lot if you could say how your void(whole sample) is used in your programm

Comment: can you debug it step by step and look if the Trips++; really increase trips?

Comment: Try `Trips +=1;` or at least `Trips = Trips + 1`

Comment: i try that but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

From your Comments

> the nOofTrips column doesn't update anymore

your `nOofTrips` column is `int` so you should not give single quotes.

**Try This:**

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE [tbl_bill_addtrips] SET nOofTrips= " + Trips.ToString() + " where  RouteFrom='" + this.txtBillRouteFrom.Text + "'and RouteTo='" + this.txtBillRouteTo.Text + "'";
```

**Note :** I Suggest you to use parameterised queries to avoid Sql Injection Attacks.

**With Parameterised Queries:**

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE [tbl_bill_addtrips] SET nOofTrips=@nooftrips where  RouteFrom=@routefrom and RouteTo=@routeto";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nooftrips",Trips);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@routefrom",this.txtBillRouteFrom.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@routeto",this.txtBillRouteTo.Text);
```

**Solution 2:**  Try this:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_bill_addtrips SET nOofTrips= " + Trips.ToString() + " where  RouteFrom='" + this.txtBillRouteFrom.Text.Trim() + "' and RouteTo='" + this.txtBillRouteTo.Text.Trim() + "'";
```

**Solution 3:**

Replace this:

```
if (From.ToString() == txtBillRouteFrom.Text && to.ToString() == txtBillRouteTo.Text)
```

With This:

```
if (From.ToString().Equals(txtBillRouteFrom.Text.Trim()) && to.ToString().Equals(txtBillRouteTo.TextTrim()))
```

Comment: your table name can lead to confusions so please enclose your table name in square brackets => `[tbl_bill_addtrips]`. see my edited answer.

Comment: an error appear

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[tbl_bill_addtrips] SET noOfTrips=1 where  RouteFrom='ASD' and RouteTo='ASD'' at line 1

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: which error are you getting please copy paste as it is.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[tbl_bill_addtrips] SET noOfTrips=1 where RouteFrom='ASD' and RouteTo='ASD'' at line 1

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: which query you are using parameterised query or non parameterised query?

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: use query in my `Solution2` it works perfectly

Comment: i want to happen, that everytime the RouteFrom is equal to txtBillRouteFrom and RouteTo is equal to TxtBillRouteTo. the Trips must increment by 1

Comment: i use the non-paramatised query

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: if you use the second solution it should work, what is the error now?

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: Okay edited my `solution 2` by enclosing table name in square brackets `[]` please try  `solution 2` now .

Comment: i use the solution2 this is the error:  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[tbl_bill_addtrips] SET nOofTrips= 1 where  RouteFrom='ASD' and RouteTo='ASD'' at line 1

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: okay then dont enclose table name in square brackets but call `Trim()` textbox values check edited `solution 2`

Comment: ohh :( nothing happen when i click the button i do call already the Trim() in textbox

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol: could you please join this chat room? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42712/sql-query-insertion-failure

Comment: i cannot join, low in reputation :( i am begginer in programming

Comment: @GeLoCapongcol:  please add me in gmail -> sudhakar.tillapudi@gmail.com and ping me

Answer (score 0):

Now try this, :)

```
    string MyConS = "SERVER=localhost;" +
                 "DATABASE=prototype_db;" +
                 "UID=root;";`enter code here`


                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConS);
                    MySqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
                    conn.Open();
                    comm.CommandText = "Select RouteTo,RouteFrom,nOofTrips from tbl_bill_addtrips where RouteFrom = '" + txtBillRouteFrom.Text + "' and RouteTo ='" + txtBillRouteTo.Text + "'";
                    MySqlDataReader Reader;
                    Reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
int Trips = 1;                    
while (Reader.Read())
                    {

                        string to = Reader["RouteTo"].ToString();
                        string From = Reader["RouteFrom"].ToString();
                        Trips = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["nOofTrips"].ToString());


                        if (From.ToString() == txtBillRouteFrom.Text && to.ToString() == txtBillRouteTo.Text)
                        {
                            Trips++;
                            MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConS);
                            conn2.Open();
                            MySqlCommand command = conn2.CreateCommand();
                            command.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_bill_addtrips SET nOofTrips= '" + Trips.ToString() + "' where  RouteFrom='" + this.txtBillRouteFrom.Text + "'and RouteTo='" + this.txtBillRouteTo.Text + "'";


                        }
                    }
```

**Regards

Ali Muhammad**